# Selecting a random element from a PHP associative array

Tags: php, random, associative-array

I've got an associative array in PHP and want to select a random key/value pair out of it. Here's what I have so far:

Initialize.

```
$locations = array();
```

Loops through a SQL query and adds key/val pairs:

```
array_push($locations, "'$location_id' => '$location_name'");
```

Later on, I select a random index of the array:

```
$rand = array_rand($locations);
```

Rand is just a number. So locations[$rand] gives me something like:

```
'1' => 'Location 1'
```

OK great, an assoc array element. At this point, I do not know the key of this assoc array, so I've tried the following things:

```
foreach($locations[$rand] as $loc_id => $location_name) { 
    echo "$key : $value<br/>\n";
}

$loc_id, $location_name = each($locations[$rand]);

$location_name = $locations[key($rand)];
```

None of these 3 attempts work. They all throw errors like "Passed variable is not an array".

I'm sure there's some simple 1 liner that can pluck a random key/value pair from the array. Or my syntax is off. I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
$key = array_rand($array);
$value = $array[$key];
```

Your problem is in `array_push($locations, "'$location_id' => '$location_name'");`. Do this instead: `$locations[$location_id] = $location_name;`. Then `array_rand($location)` will return a random `$location_id;` and you can get the name with `$name = $locations[$location_id]`.

Comment: Your problem is in `array_push($locations, "'$location_id' => '$location_name'");`. Do this instead: `$locations[$location_id] = $location_name;`. Then `array_rand($location)` will return a random `$location_id`; and you can get the name with `$name = $locations[$location_id]`.

Comment: you're all correct, of course - i just picked this one bc i work best with example code. and yeah, i'm pretty embarrassed about the push not being correct. i code a ton in perl (w hashes) so i should have known better!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 6):

[array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns a key from the array, not a value. You can just use:

```
$location_name = $locations[$rand];
```

To get the location name.

Here's a full example: http://codepad.org/zR2YdMGN

Just click submit a few times, you'll see the random working.

Comment: This still doesn't give the key.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Then the claim (`$rand` is just a number) from the OP is wrong. And I was foolish enough to not verify this claim.

Comment: @M_rk It returns the key :) I updated my answer so that it has a link to the PHP Man page for array_rand

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one line:

```php
$randomValue = array_rand(array_flip(['value_1', 'value_2']))
```

You will get the value right away instead of the key.