# php associative array select 1 random value with key

Tags: php, arrays

I need to random a single element from the array. I have code ;

```
     if (isset($_POST['losuj'])) {
   $arr = [
   'chleb' => 'skiny/1.jpg',
   'mienso' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
   'mienso2' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
   'mienso3' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
   'mienso4' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
   'mienso5' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
   'Hasasdasd' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
   ];

     foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $keys = array_rand( $arr, 1);
        echo $keys;
     }
 }
```

And it`s didn`t working. Any tips ?

Comment: `$keys` variable displaying what? Refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? If you are looking for a single random element remove the foreach and simply use the call to array_rand once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a random element from a PHP associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209127/selecting-a-random-element-from-a-php-associative-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_keys to get the keys in a indexed array.
The just use array_rand just like you did to pick one and echo the $arr associative key.

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$random = $keys[array_rand($keys,1)];
Echo $random . " => " . $arr[$random];
```

https://3v4l.org/miacb

Comment: I need to have got value and key not only .jpg file.

Comment: @Season6 See edit. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes ! Thanks very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_rand($arr,1)` without `foreach` loop

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\csgolos\freeCase.php on line 65

Comment: `$a = array_rand($arr,1);` `echo $a[0];`

Comment: Then this only echo the first letter of the key if we have got chleb then the echo gives - c

Comment: `$a = array_rand($arr,1);` `echo $a`. It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

With PHP we can use the function array_rand()

More information can be found at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_rand.asp

```
$arr = [
  'chleb' => 'skiny/1.jpg',
  'mienso' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
  'mienso2' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
  'mienso3' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
  'mienso4' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
  'mienso5' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
  'Hasasdasd' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
];

$randomEntry = array_rand($arr, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this without the loop

```
$key = array_rand($arr);
echo $arr[$key];
```

full example

```
$arr = [
   'chleb' => 'skiny/1.jpg',
   'mienso' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
   'mienso2' => 'skiny/3.jpg',
   'mienso3' => 'skiny/4.jpg',
   'mienso4' => 'skiny/5.jpg',
   'mienso5' => 'skiny/6.jpg',
   'Hasasdasd' => 'skiny/7.jpg',
 ];

$key = array_rand($arr);
echo $key;
echo $arr[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the '.jpg' files meant to all be the same except for one? Because randomly choosing between 7 files when 6 are the same is going to return the same file more than often.

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($arr);
echo $arr[$rand_keys];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should print array result like below,

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($arr, 1);
echo $arr[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $input = array(
    'chleb' => 'skiny/1.jpg',
    'mienso' => 'skiny/2.jpg',
    'mienso2' => 'skiny/3.jpg',
    'mienso3' => 'skiny/4.jpg',
    'mienso4' => 'skiny/5.jpg',
    'mienso5' => 'skiny/6.jpg',
    'Hasasdasd' => 'skiny/7.jpg',
);

foreach($input as $key => $value) {
    $keys = array_rand( $input, 1);
    echo $input[$keys];
}
?>
```

Comment: or change $input to $arr